# Current WordPress Page Title as Search Parameter into A Tag <a href=“www.domain.com/s?=currentpagetitle”></a>

Tags: php, widgets, url-rewriting, urls, html

i would like to include an affiliate link as a widget which inserts the title of the respective page as search parameter.

```
<a href="www.amazon.com/s?=titleofthepage">Link</a>
```

I have already created a shortcode in the functions.php with get_the_title

```
function post_title_shortcode(){
$variable = get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode('post_title','post_title_shortcode');
```

and it is called [post_title]

However

```
<a href="www.amazon.de/s?=[post_title]"></a>
```

didn't work. Does anyone have any other idea how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shortcode is getting the title, but you haven't told it to return anything, so a small tweak should fix things:

```
<?php
function post_title_shortcode(){
    return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode('post_title','post_title_shortcode');
?>
```

You could also continue setting `get_the_title()` to `$variable` and add a line to `return $variable`, but the above is the simplest, shortest option.

Comment: Also note, shortcodes may not work in widgets at all if you haven't used code to enable it, so it may be worth editing the widget itself to output the title instead of adding a shortcode into the mix.